# get list from db.query

Tags: razor

I want to know if there is a way to retrive the sql result in a list.
I have: 
 var ingredients = db.Query("Select * FROM Ingredients");

Is there a way to get that in a list, since I don't want to use the foreach loop,
I want to get the result in specific index.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Query`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.query%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) method returns an `IEnumerable<object>`. So you could use the `.ToList()` extension method to get a `List<object>`.

```
var ingredients = db.Query("Select * FROM Ingredients").ToList();
```

and then be able to access individual elements by index:

```
var fifthIngredient = ingredients[4];
```

If course before doing that you should make sure that this list contains at least the number of elements you are trying to access the index at, otherwise you will get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` at runtime when you attempt to access an element at a larger index.

Your goal is not quite clear so unfortunately it's hard to offer you some better alternatives.